# Evaluate $ \lim_{n\to \infty} ( \lim_{x\to0} (1+\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(2x)+ \cdots + \tan^2(nx)))^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} ( \lim_{x\to0} (1+\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(2x)+ \cdots + \tan^2(nx)))^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}} $

The answer should be $ {e}^\frac{1}{3} $

I haven't encountered problems like this before and I'm pretty confused, thank you.

I guess we must use the remarkable limit of $ \frac{\tan(x)}{x} $ when $ x $ approaches $ 0 $ by dividing and then multiplaying with $x$.

Comment: Are you sue about the place of exponent?

Comment: Yeah, it looks just like that in the book : https://i.imgur.com/ibS7tax.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x\to 0$

- $\tan x= x+o(x^2)$

then

$$(1+\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(2x)+ \cdots + \tan^2(nx)))^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}} = (1+x^2+4x^2+...+n^2x^2+o(x^2)) ^ {\frac{1}{n^3x^2}}=\large{e^{\frac{\log(1+x^2+4x^2+...+n^2x^2+o(x^2))}{n^3x^2}}=e^{\frac{x^2+4x^2+...+n^2x^2+o(x^2)}{n^3x^2}}=e^{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6n^3}+o(1)} \stackrel{x\to0}\to e^{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6n^3}}}$$

and for $n\to \infty$

$$\Large{e^{\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6n^3}}}\to e^\frac13$$

Comment: Didn't think about using $ f^g  = e^{glnf} $. Thanks!

Comment: @SADBOYS Yes it’s indeed a standard trick for the limit in this form! Note that you should accept Mark Viola answer since he gave the correct insight to solve properly the limit. Bye

Comment: @gimusi Have we used the continuity of the logarithm to take the limit outside? Or it isn't necessary? I ask because I've used the same strategy but I found the limit stuck inside the parentheses and it seems like I can only use Taylor for the tangents, so I've taken it out using the continuity. But I'm not sure if it is allowed or even if it is necessary and could be ignored. Thanks for your time if you will answer!

Comment: @Mephlip No I’ve just used Taylor’s expansion, the limits are taken only were indicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch.  First write

$$\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \tan^2(kx) \right)^{1/n^3x^2}=e^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^2(kx))}  $$

Now, find the limit as $x\to 0$ exploiting the continuity of the exponential function.  For example, L'Hospital's Rule can be applied twice.  You may also use asymptotic equivalents (or Taylor's Theorem) if you are familiar with those.

You will arrive at the sum $\frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$ as the exponent.

Can you finish now?

Comment: very nice and compact, I've just some doubts with this kind of double limit, are we allowed to take first the approximation for the inner limit ant then take the limit for $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @gimusi We can find the interior limit (no approximation), which is $\frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$.  Then taking the exterior limit, we arrive at $1/3$.

Comment: @MarkViola Then my solution is not rigorous since I used approximation in the first step?

Comment: @MarkViola I've fixed following your suggestion, now it look more clear and rigorous to me!

Comment: @gimusi Your result is fine since you retained terms that are $o(x^2)$.

Comment: @gimusi Well done. (+1)

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks Mark your suggestions are always a great chance to learn more! (my +1 already given!)